# A random surface seems to appear in my render but I cannot see it in 3d Viewport

Tags: rendering, light

Apologies, I'm a pretty novice user and I'm trying to render some artwork for my job quite quickly.

I've created this set up with lots of objects emitting light and want one flat background to let the light bounce off of. The background is textured. For some reason when I render, a second surface appears closer to the camera than I want the background, cutting off some of the light-emitting objects.

[image]
https://i.stack.imgur.com/j1tSL.jpg - 
the left is the 3d viewport with the face behind it, but on the right you can see it rendering with a surface appearing closer to the camera, and the lights behind being  cut off.

Any help would be really appreciated!

Comment: Hiding things in the viewport doesn't necessarily hide them in the render. I wouldn't know how your scene is divided into collections/view layers, but assuming it's quite simple, your first shot is to Alt-H unhide everything in Object Mode.